# Wordpress - footer until bottom of page

Tags: css, wordpress

In all my pages the page stops half way the page. I would like it to flow naturally to 100% of my screensize. I found this [article](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) but can't seem to get it to work for me. Could anyone help me out and perhaps have a look? (I always try using Chrome>Inspect element)

If I set the main-container to min-height 100% it reaches the full length of the page, except my footer is displayed beneath this.

[About Page](http://tomm3ke.be/?page_id=6)

Comment: Did you search stackoverflow before asking this ? You will find a lot of answers : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=footer+height+100%25

Comment: When you set `min-height:100%;` the `div` main-container get the height of its parent. In this case is the `body` element. In your article, he's using `position : asbolute; bottom: 0px; ` on its footer.

Comment: Yes I did, I used a different search term though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your looking for is a sticky footer. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/wWBPJ/1/

The idea is that the bottom margin is the negative value of the footers height