# Sticky Footer problems.. Here's another one

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

Firstly, apologies for what appears to be a very common question, looking at the amount of similar questions, you are forgiven for being annoyed at yet another, but regardless of all the others that I have read (and tried to implement), and many other links found on Google, I'm still struggling to solve my problem, so I'm sorry, but here goes..

The footer I have is fine when the main content is longer than the browser window, but when there is very little content, rather than sticking to the bottom of the browser window, it sticks to the bottom of the main content, leaving a horrible blank space below the footer.

I've created a simple(ish) fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z67PM/) using a stripped down version of my code.. here is the code for those that are able to see the issue without "fiddling"..

```
<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <header class="5grid-layout" id="site-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u">
                    <div id="logo">
                            <h1 class="mobileUI-site-name">HEADER</h1>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
    <!-- Main -->
    <div id="main-wrapper" class="subpage">
        <div class="5grid-layout">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u">MAIN CONTENT </div>
                          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    <!-- Footer -->
    <div id="footer-wrapper">
        <footer class="5grid-layout" id="site-footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u">PROBLEM FOOTER</div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

and here is the css..

```
#header-wrapper {
    background: #12ff00;
    height: 110px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.0em 0 1em 0;
}
#main-wrapper {
    border-top: 3px solid #662d91;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #662d91;
    background: #ff5a00;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em 0 2em 0;
 
   
}
#footer-wrapper {
    background: #ff00fc;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
    height: 100px;
   
}
```

Granted, a lot of the above Divs aren't needed for the sake of this demo, but I have left them in just in case it is one of these thats causing the problem. I'm still new to this, so I honestly have no idea.

so basically, how on earth do I get that footer to behave, previous attempts based on other Stack Overflow answers have left me with either no footer, or a footer that sits in the center of the screen regardless of whether there is a lot or little content.

Any help will be gratefully received.

Comment: Get this: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ working by itself in your dev environment. Then, merge your new site into the stick footer code.

Comment: Looks like this question got it sorted. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15799420/1003940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
}
#main-wrapper {
   height:100%;
}
```

Here's a working **[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/Z67PM/9/)**

#### UPDATES:

I've changed a few things in your code, but now its working!

Here are the changes:

- added a `#container` for the header and main divs.
- I've changed the footer `padding` from `em` to `px`, because I need precise height.
- I gave the `main-wrapper`'s background to `#container`
- and the `border-bottom` to footer as `border-top`

**[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/Z67PM/43/)**

Comment: I have tried it, and its a weird one. on pages with little content, it pushes the footer down below the bottom of the browser window, which isn't too bad, but on a page where there is a lot of content, it cuts the content off at the bottom. see here.. http://jsfiddle.net/Z67PM/26/

Comment: Than you should use `min-height: 100%` for `#main-wrapper`. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Z67PM/30/ .

Comment: Thanks for reply again, but still not quite there.. that works great for pages with a lot of content, but it pushes the footer off the bottom when there isn't as much.. like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Z67PM/31

Comment: You sir, are a star! thank you so much.. I spent hours last night playing with your fiddle, came close, but your latest edit has worked a treat! thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Glad that I could help!

Answer (score 2):

I have answered this question before

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12580337/1453921)

Or see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWBPJ/1/) for a working example of a sticky footer.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="header"></div>     
</div>      
<div class="footer"></div>
```

CSS

```
* {margin: 0;}
html, body {height: 100%;}

.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -200px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */}

.footer { height: 200px;background-color:#000;}
```

The idea is that the bottom margin is the negative value of the footers height

Answer (score 0):

The way I ussualy do this is using
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

If you can, try to stick close to that, it has compatibility with older browsers.

I didn't find better alternatives to this and is well explained

Comment: Please try to include the detail of the external site, that way if the site is unavailable your answer will still be useful

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this before, but will give it yet another go if all else fails.